# Varnish Installation

Tags: cpanel, varnish, centos6, whm

I'm running a VPS with cPanel / WHM 58.0 (Build 24) and Centos 6.8. I'm attempting to install the varnish cache on the server to improve response but I get this error during the install:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks 
Setting up Install Process 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile 
* EA4: 198.245.49.52 
* base: centos.serverspace.co.uk 
* epel: epel.check-update.co.uk 
* extras: centos.hyve.com 
* updates: centos.serverspace.co.uk 
Resolving Dependencies 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.3-1.el7 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: varnish-libs = 4.1.3-1.el7 for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.1)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-sysv for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: jemalloc for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.3)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.2)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.0)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.4)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvgz.so()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnish.so()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishcompat.so()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libvcc.so()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el6 will be installed 
---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.3-1.el7 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-sysv for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
---> Package varnish-libs.x86_64 0:4.1.3-1.el7 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: varnish-libs-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-libs-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 
--> Finished Dependency Resolution 
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) 
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) 
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) 
Error: Package: varnish-libs-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) 
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: systemd-sysv 
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: systemd-units 
Error: Package: varnish-libs-4.1.3-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1) 
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) 
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem 
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Obviously a dependancy is missing but I'm at a loss to resolve it. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install too new Varnish to too old Centos.

What repo are you installing Varnish package from?

Run `yum list glibc` on you machine a examine version.
As it is Centos 6.8, it would be probably 2.12-something and Varnish 4.1.x need at least 2.15 according to your dump.

You have to try either older version or Varnish, or upgrade your distro to newer version.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Rastislav. You're correct after running that command it confirmed glibc 2.12 was running on the machine. I should have thought of that. The VPS provider had installed a version of cPanel / WHM a few versions behind the latest too so had to update that. Will update glibc now and re-attempt the varnish install.